# Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader continue on incorrect number of tokens

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch `FlatFileItemReader` to parse csv files. Every now and then I get an ill-formated line and the application completely crashes with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 11 actual 18
```

Is there any way to tell the `FlatFileItemReader` to continue (throw exception and continue or ignore and continue) without it completely exiting the application.

I'm guessing I may need to extend the FlatFileItemReader to make this happen as there does not appear to be any setting for this. Any suggestions on how best to proceed and make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a class that extended the `DefaultLineMapper` that gets injected into the `FlatFileItemReader`.

I then overrode mapLine method like this:

```
@Override
public T mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
    T t = null;

    try {
        t = super.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unable to parse line number <<{}>> with line <<{}>>.", lineNumber, line);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure SkipLogic for your batch jobs
Here's a [link to doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip)

Basically, if you are using Java Config to manage your Batch Job 
you can do something like this

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .processor(processor)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(10)
                .skip(RuntimeException.class)
                .listener(skipListener) // if you want to add
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same as your issue, but I was getting the same error when parsing a caret "^" delimited file that contained quote **"** characters.

The **"** character is intended to be used to *to extend a field across line endings or to enclose a String which contains the delimiter*. So my line that looks like this:

```
^3500 LCF Gas:  109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab^Chevrolet^3500 LCF Gas^109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab^L
```

would be parsed like it has only 2 fields:

1. 3500 LCF Gas:  109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab^Chevrolet^3500 LCF Gas^109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab
2. L

What I really wanted is 5 fields:

1. 3500 LCF Gas:  109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab
2. Chevrolet
3. 3500 LCF Gas
4. 109" Wheelbase, Reg Cab
5. L

My file didn't contain any ampersands so I changed the `DelimitedLinetokenizer` default quoteCharacter from **"** to **&**.

```
lineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter('&');
```

Which fixed my issue that resulted in the same error when using Spring Batch.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by setting the property "`strict`" to **false** for the property "`lineTokenizer`" from `DefaultLineMapper` .